# Python getopt too many arguments

Tags: python, getopt

I am at a dead end. I am trying to pass arguments into a Linux to run certain operations. I want to avoid the user from entering too many paramters.

For example the desired running of the script would be as such:

```
./audit.py -a
```

I want to prevent the following:

```
./audit.py -af
```

This seems to be running whatever is specified for 'a' and then 'f'. In this case if it is like '-af' then I need it to quit with a sys.exit(). My len(sys.argv[1:]) always produces a result of 1 no matter how parameters I put in.

```
import getopts
import sys
def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'v:adfh')
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        sys.exit(str(err))
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 1:
        sys.exit('Invalid')

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ('-v', '--volume'):
            print 'Volumes'
        elif len(sys.argv[2:]) != 0:
            sys.exit('Too many arguments')
        elif o in ('-a', '--agent'):
            print 'Full audit of agents only'
        elif o in ('-d', '--device'):
            print 'Full audit of device only'
        elif o in ('-f', '--full'):
            print 'Full audit of device/agents'
        elif o in ('-h', '--help'):
            sys.exit('Help Section')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you want to check how many options were specified, why not examine `opts`?

Comment: Just for my understanding: why don't you want prevent clustering of the options?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `sys.argv[1:] is ['-af']` and if you will check for lenght of ['-af'] is 1 which is why `if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 1:` is always false. Instead if you want to check the length of first argument either you need to use `len(sys.argv[1:][0])` or else for each of the arguments lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sys.argv[1:]` produces a *slice*. In other words, it's a list. In your case, it's something like `['-af']`. So of course, the length will always be `1` except if you passed no parameters. Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
if not all(i < 1 for i in sys.argv[1:]):
    sys.exit('Invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at option clustering. There does not seem to be any facility in [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) to disable this feature. However, you probably shouldn't be using this package, anyway. Would [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) perhaps be more suitable for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but you might be glad to look at a library I was very happy to find.

[docopts](http://docopt.org/) - there is a great video describing how to use

This is a great tool, you just describe your arguments in the module document section, e.g.;

```
'''
Usage:
   myprog -a -v <volumes>...
   myprog -f
   myprog -h | --help
'''
import docopt
args=docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

This will produce the following dictionary if run as `myprog -a -v one two three`;

```
{
  "--help": false, 
  "-a": true, 
  "-f": false, 
  "-h": false, 
  "-v": true, 
  "": [
    "myprog", 
    "one", 
    "two", 
    "three"
  ]
}
```